# Laravel: How to get specific column data of M:M relationship in array format in all row of a another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel eloquent query to get data from M:M relationship

```
person_table : id, name_of_person
skills_table : id, name_of_skill
M:M table    : person_table_id , skills_table_id
```

and result will be

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: harat,
  skills: [
    'php',
    'laravel',
    'reactjs',
    'nodejs',
  ]
}
```

Comment: See the following documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: when i fetch using with() method the whole collection comes in but i want data in one dimensional array

Answer (score -1):

If you check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), you will see that you can use [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) so you can eager load the `skills`.

So, you should have a code like this:

```php
$person = Person::with('skills')->first();
```

And then if you do `$person->skills` you should have a `Collection` (not an array) holding all the Skills like this `id: 1, name: php`, `id:2, name: laravel`, etc.

So, you should format your resulting models like:

```php
$person->map(function (Person $person) {
    return [
        'id' => $person->id,
        'name' => $person->name,
        'skills' => $person->skills->pluck('name'),
    ];
});
```

You can also take advantage of [`API Resources`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#concept-overview) so you can format your output.

Comment: Hey @matiaslauriti for the answer, is it possible with one eloquent query?

Comment: You cannot format that output with one eloquent query, you need to run the first code (it is an eloquent query) and then format that to your desired output.

Comment: can i use the subqueries with eloquent in a single query.

Comment: What do you mean? What would you like to do with the query? The query I shared with you is as perfect as it is. What would you like to change and why?

Comment: i want to get data in a single query from the database so that reduce the load from database.

Comment: No, you eager load using `with`. read the documentation. that is the most performant way of doing what you want to do.